# What does “I hit Delete” mean?

Tags: meaning

I just deleted my own question about the sentence in the Time magazine (July 8) article titled “The Happiness of Pursuit” (http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,2146449,00.html) as I noticed that I overlooked a word (poor) in the quoted sentence.

However, I came across another line I cannot make out in the same copy block:

> “Rich isn’t just better; it’s much better. That is how things shake
>   out at the national and global level. At the individual and community
>   level, it can be much different. If you’re rich, your experiences are
>   not the same as every other rich person’s, and the same is true if
>   you’re poor. “A reporter once asked me, ‘Yes or no, does money make
>   people happy? No scientific waffling, Just yes or no.” says
>   psychologist Edward Diener of the University of Illinois, “**I hit
>   Delete**.”

What does the ending phrase, “I hit Delete” mean? Is it the same as the 'Delete’ practice as we do, and I did on my question an hour before in EL&U site?

Comment: A monk asked Jōshū, "Has a dog Buddha-nature or not?" Jōshū answered, "Mu."

Comment: MetaED. I was surprised and pleased to know you are familiar with the very first phrase of the Rule (chapter)1 of 趙州狗子 of Zen classic, 無門関. Joshu taught the monk that a single letter of 無 – nothing - is the key gate to enter Zen world. ‘The Lecture on 無門関’ written by Japanese Zen priest, Genpo Yamamoto at hand is published in 1960. It seems I was absorbed in Zen, and bought the book around that time. Good to see your unique comment I didn’t fancy to meet in this site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume the reporter asked the question via email, and so Diener simply hit the Delete key on his email application. In other words,

> *"This [the reporter's question] is a stupid question – I'm not going to bother with this."*

As for it being idiomatic English, expressions like that one are used every now and then, where we use computer or technology jargon to explain something, perhaps metaphorically, such as "[rebooting my life](http://www.cparker15.com/2011/11/rebooting-my-life/)" (when *turning over a new leaf*), or "pulling the plug" when we want to, say, abandon a project.

Comment: Because D of delete is capital letter, it occurred to me that Delete could mean “Delete” tag of e-mail as an after-thought. But I couldn’t believe at first that a reporter could ask the renowned scientist a question in such a blunt way as “No scientific waffling, just yes or no.”

Comment: Cont. by e-mail, not during an interview.

Comment: I think the bluntness of the question was an attempt to try to "corner" the psychologist, that is, to get him to acknowledge that a certain viewpoint has some validity. Considering the person being interviewed spent six years studying the issue (from the article: "A massive study Diener led .. analyzed the responses of 806,526 people in 135 countries collected over the course of six years"), and reporter was insisting on a one-word response, I can't blame Diener for hitting 'Delete'. You're right – the reporter was being either rude or ignorant, if not both.